# How to spread styles object passed down to a styled component as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a custom text component that takes an optional style props:

```
<TextComponent style={{ color: 'red' }}>Test</TextComponent>
```

Then I generate the CSS of the styled component based on the variant but I also want to somehow apply the custom optional styling that might be passed as a prop. I imagine I'd need to spread it somewhere, but I couldn't figure out where.

```
const TextComponent = ({ style, ...rest }) => {
    return <StyledText {...rest} />;
};

const StyledText = styled.Text`
    fontFamily: ${(props: any) => styles.text.fontFamily};
    color: ${(props: any) => styles.text.color};
    fontWeight: ${(props: any) => styles.text.fontWeight};
    fontSize: ${(props: any) => styles.text.fontSize};
    lineHeight: ${(props: any) => styles.text.lineHeight};
`;

export default TextComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Styled components can accept object instead string.

```
const styles = {
    h1: {
        fontFamily: fonts.GUARDIAN_EGYP_LIGHT,
        color: colors.gray900,
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontSize: '36px',
        lineHeight: '40px',
    },
    h2: {
        fontFamily: fonts.GUARDIAN_EGYP_LIGHT,
        color: colors.gray900,
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontSize: '30px',
        lineHeight: '39px',
    },
    h3: {
        fontFamily: fonts.GUARDIAN_EGYP_LIGHT,
        color: colors.gray900,
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontSize: '24px',
        lineHeight: '34px',
    }
};

const Component = styled.div(p => ({
  fontFamily: styles[p.variant].fontFamily,
  color: styles[p.variant].color,
  fontWeight: styles[p.variant].fontWeight,
  fontSize: styles[p.variant].fontSize,
  lineHeight: styles[p.variant].lineHeight
}))

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <Component variant="h1">Component</Component>
  </div>;
```